# Improve Performance of drawBitmap and Frame rate of game thread (android)

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, frame-rate

I have  a game thread which draws on surface view. It processes game variables and then draws on canvas.  **board** is a bitmap which would be drawn on canvas of the view. callDrawHelper re-draws on  board, first simple **background** image (same size as board). Then clusters list has set of images to be drawn on canvas based on game variable data. This entire process executes each frame.

callDrawHelper takes close to 80 milliseconds, which is highest components of thread processing. This really lowers the frame rate as well.   How can I improve performance this code segment.

```
protected void callDrawHelper() {

    Canvas gfx = drawJustBackground();
        for (int i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++) {

            PieceCluster cluster = clusters.get(i);
            if (cluster.isVisible) {
                gfx.drawBitmap(cluster.Picture, cluster.BoardLocation.left,
                        cluster.BoardLocation.top, null);
            }
        }


}

 protected Canvas drawJustBackground() {
    Canvas gfx = new Canvas(board);
    gfx.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    return gfx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's the problem without further investigation. I would start with using Traceview to analyze CPU usage as suggested here: [Android drawBitmap Performance For Lots of Bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981707/android-drawbitmap-performance-for-lots-of-bitmaps) Also make sure that your images are already scaled as suggested here: [Improve performance of Canvas.drawBitmap() on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911587/improve-performance-of-canvas-drawbitmap-on-android).